# Getting error when performing aptly mirror create in ubuntu - Focal

Tags: ubuntu, apt

`enter code here`

aptly mirror create -architectures=amd64 -with-sources=true -with-udebs=true focal-main http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main
Downloading http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease...
Success downloading http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease
gpgv: Signature made Thu 23 Apr 2020 01:34:17 PM EDT using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpgv: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpgv: keydb_search failed: invalid packet
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found
gpgv: Signature made Thu 23 Apr 2020 01:34:17 PM EDT using RSA key ID 991BC93C
gpgv: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=00)
gpgv: keydb_search failed: invalid packet
gpgv: Can't check signature: public key not found

Looks like some keys are missing in your trusted keyring, you may consider importing them from keyserver:

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 871920D1991BC93C

Sometimes keys are stored in repository root in file named Release.key, to import such key:

wget -O - https://some.repo/repository/Release.key | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg --import

Looks like some keys are missing in your trusted keyring, you may consider importing them from keyserver:

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 871920D1991BC93C

Sometimes keys are stored in repository root in file named Release.key, to import such key:

wget -O - https://some.repo/repository/Release.key | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg --import

ERROR: unable to fetch mirror: verification of detached signature failed: exit status 2

Answer (score 0):

https://www.aptly.info/doc/aptly/mirror/create/ mentions that "If aptly is running on Debian/Ubuntu machine, it would be good idea to import archive signing keys shipped with the operating system" and then provides an example for importing the debian key.

Since you're on Ubuntu, you'll want to modify the example command slightly, to be:

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg --export | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg --import
```

On my installation of focal, that consists of 3 keys.

That said, the command in the warning text you received

```
gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring trustedkeys.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 871920D1991BC93C
```

should grab the keys you need from Ubuntu's own keyserver (as of this moment, it grabs 2 of the 3 keys in /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg).